# What do Red Minus signs mean on my desktop icons?

Tags: windows-10, icons, shortcuts, desktop

Not a major issue, but not long ago my desktop icons were tagged with little red minus signs (technically white minus sign, red background).  Here's a picture:

[image: Red Minuses]

I tried clicking on the folders & they opened like normal.  I didn't see anything out of the ordinary in the file details.  The issue resolved itself when I rebooted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by OneDrive.
Newer Windows 10 versions at some point auto-activated OneDrive for every user that logged in to Windows with a Microsoft-account.
On top of that OneDrive automatically setup the Documents and Desktop folders of that user to Synchronize to OneDrive.

Now: When you login to Windows and OneDrive has problems connecting to the OneDrive servers on the Internet it will show that Minus icon to indicate the file/folder couldn't be synced. You will see a green check-mark icon if the sync is succesfull.

Answer (score 0):

That icons is from OneDrive. I'm not entirely sure.

I think is from a software that use to Sync files from a server.

[Icons Description](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/what-do-the-onedrive-icons-mean-11143026-8000-44f8-aaa9-67c985aa49b3)

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.